# How to bring text to leftside and 30% from bottom up in output video using ffmpeg drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I got some code from stack overflow which generates text animation.

In this code, the text is coming in the middle. **I want the text on left side and 30 to 40% up from bottom**.

I tried changing x and y parameters but it wasn't successful.

**below is the code**

```
ffmpeg -i output_with_logo1.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=Mangal.ttf: text='कॉपर कैन्यन, सिएरा माद्रे, मेक्सिको।': fontcolor=red: fontsize=60: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=if(lt(t\,3)\,(-h+((3*h-200)*t/6))\,(h-200)/2):enable='between(t,2.9,50)',
```

```
drawtext=fontfile=Mangal.ttf: text='कॉपर कैन्यन, सिएरा माद्रे, मेक्सिको ।': fontcolor=yellow: fontsize=60: x=if(lt(t\,4)\,(-w+((3*w-tw)*t/8))\,(w-tw)/2): y=(h-100)/2:enable='between(t,3.5,50)',
```

```
drawtext=fontfile=Mangal.ttf: text='कॉपर कैन्यन, सिएरा माद्रे, मेक्सिको ।': fontcolor=blue: fontsize=60: x=if(lt(t\,5)\,(2*w-((3*w+tw)*t/10))\,(w-tw)/2): y=h/2:enable='between(t,4.5,50)',
```

```
drawtext=fontfile=Mangal.ttf: text='कॉपर कैन्यन, सिएरा माद्रे, मेक्सिको ।': fontcolor=black: fontsize=60: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=if(lt(t\,6)\,(2*h-((3*h-100)*t/12))\,(h+100)/2):enable='between(t,5.5,50)'[out]" out101.mp4
```

Comment: Are you able to format this to span multiple lines? It would help for readability.

Comment: I edit the code part for readability purpose. Thanks for your reply @Gregg.